# Column type in grails not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This is my model.

```
class Review {
String review
Date date
int numberOfComments
String status
static belongsTo = [game:Game, user:User]
static hasMany=[comment:Comment]
static mapping ={
    numberOfComments    defaultValue: "0"
    review type: 'text'
}

static constraints = {

}
```

when I inputted 400 character text it generated this error

[image]

I don't know why the review type: 'text' is not working. can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact grails GORM sometimes have problems with updating column types, especially if they contain any data. Try to delete selected column/table in database and restart application.

Ensure also that you have changed in conf/DataSource.groovy

> dbCreate = "update"

to

> dbCreate = "create-drop"

Edited: Firstly I didn't notice that you are using h2 db. Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453787/long-string-data-type-in-h2-databases) for text type in h2 database.

Comment: Do I really need to change it to create-drop? I don't wanna lose all I have in my database, What's the difference anyways?

Comment: in dev I use 'create-drop', in production I use 'update'. that's the easiest way to ensure that columns/fields have the type you want.

Comment: so i change to create-drop then  static mapping = {
    review type : 'clob' 
}?

Comment: first change to create-drop and don't change mapping. it's possible that h2 created this field as a regular varchar. if after  restart it still dosn't work change mapping to clob.

Comment: do you use h2 in production too ? you might get an issue if you use clob type when moving to your other env

Comment: what do you mean production? im stil on development

Comment: your code works... please look for differences between my and your project: https://github.com/majkelo/ReviewTest

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an sqlType instead like

```
class Email {

    String body

    static mapping = {
        body sqlType: "longtext"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it a `blob` type

```
static mapping = {
    review (type:’blob’)
}
```

Note `type` is default properties for Grails 2.0, if you use newer version of grails you should use `sqlType`.

Check it here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html

Comment: It says Message: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.sql.Blob