# GORM Not Recognizing type: 'text' Mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

This question is similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218991/column-type-in-grails-not-working) – but the answer does not apply here. I am currently only working in development and configured as `dbCreate: create-drop` with `url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`

Using Grails 3.0.11 – GORM seems to not recognize type:'text' mapping. Here is my model:

```
package mypackage

class Text extends Object {

    String body
    Media image

    boolean textFirst = true

    static constraints = {
        image nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        body type: 'text'
    }
}
```

Bootstrapping some data, I'm being thrown this error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Value too long for column "BODY VARCHAR(255)": "'<p>some copy... (1222)"; SQL statement:
insert into object (id, date_created, description, heading, last_updated, title, two_col, body, image_id, text_first, class) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'mypackage.Text')
```

My understanding is that the `mapping` to `type:text` should create  CLOB-type variable, which is automatically not constrained to max size 255.

### Attempted Solutions

1. `grails clean` - application is cleaned, no success
2. `grails clean-all` - this isn't a Grails 3+ method (does not work)
3. `grails clean --refresh-dependencies` – cleans, but no success
4. Swapped the order of `static constraints` and `static mapping` in the model, no success
5. Added `body maxSize: 5000` to my model constraints , no success
6. `grails url-mappings-report` strangely completes the Bootstrap without throwing an error.

### Edit 1

This might have to do with inheritance – the Text Class currently extends Object. Changing the Text model as follows, Bootstrapping succeeds. Could anyone provide me with some insight?

```
package mypackage

class Text {

    String body
    Media image

    boolean textFirst = true


    static constraints = {
        image nullable:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        body type: 'text'

    }
}
```

This is the mypackage.Object:

```
package mypackage

class Object {

    String title
    String heading
    String description

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    boolean twoCol = false

    static constraints = {
        heading nullable: true, maxSize: 3000
        description nullable: true, maxSize: 500
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
    }
}
```

### Edit 2

Renamed the `body` container to `content`, `grails clean` and it seems to be working now. Still unsure of what was going on, maybe some sort of caching issue (?) ...

Any help is awesome!! Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
static mapping = {
        body sqlType: 'text'
    }
```

Comment: No success – same error is being thrown. Even after cleaning the app. Thank you

Comment: every class in java/groovy extends Object class by default. You should rename the class to something else. Also check if "text" is not the reserved word for the database you are using.

Comment: I tried to rename the Object class and wasn't able to get the program running. Renamed `body` to `content` and it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

static mapping = {
        body type: 'text'
    }

Comment: This is the mapping given in the question.